# Function that returns the value from a closure with completion

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, closures, completionhandler

I am trying to write a function that returns a value from a Firebase request closure.

Unfortunately, I have not yet fully mastered closures and completion handlers.

I would like to use and call this function like this:

```
let name = userName(forUID: “UID01”)
```

and not like this:

```
let name = userName(forUID: "UID01") { name in
            print(name)
    }
```

The reason why I want to use it this way is because this function will be called in many places of the code and I like to keep my code as clean and concise as possible. And otherwise, I can declare a global variable and use `self.name = name` inside the function body. But if, for example, I call this function 5 times, I will have to declare 5 global variables...

The function looks like this:

```swift
func userName(forUID: String, completion: @escaping (_ name: String) -> ()) {
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("users").child(forUID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let data = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let name = data?["name"] as? String ?? ""
        completion(name)
        // ...
    })
}
```

Comment: First of all, `let name = userName(forUID: "UID01") { name in
            print(name)
    })` is wrong. The `userName` function doesn't return anything (or to be precise, it returns `Void`, so it makes no sense to store that `Void` in a variable. Secondly, since the Firebase function is asynchronous, you cannot use the `name` value like it was returned from a synchronous method. Using a completion handler is the easiest solution, but you should look into how to handle async methods, since there are some other ways as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd version is close. It should be like this:

```
userName(forUID: "UID01") { name in
  print(name)
}
```

Since you are using an async Firebase method to fetch your data, you CANNOT create a function that returns that data. That is not how async methods work.

Comment: You have an extra parentheses `)` on the last line of your code.

Comment: So I did. Thanks. (Fixed)